# DataGridView - Get row by "selected row" and double button function

Tags: c#, datagridview, rows

I have a question about getting a "name" cell from a row from a DGV previously selecting it (all the row highlighted in blue).

My DGV is simple. I have only 2 columns (id and name).

I added some values first-

```
       `dgv1.Rows.Add(1, "Hola");
        dgv1.Rows.Add(2, "Hi");
        dgv1.Rows.Add(3, "Hello");
        dgv1.Rows.Add(4, "Ciao");
        dgv1.Rows.Add(5, "Hei");`
```

then I have a button so that if I click the button (after selecting row), it can show me the name field, but I don't know how the rest works out . . .

Sorry if this question is too simple, I didn't find any similar questions on other forums.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using c# on visual studio using windows forms